# Ruby TDD and Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

Im new to testing in ruby with Rspec. I'm just wanting to write a simple test to see if the below code works. Im not sure how to do it. The code returns an acronym of a given string. thanks

```
def acronym(sentence)
  first_letters = []
  sentence.split.each do |word|
    first_letters << word[0]
  end
  first_letters.join
end

describe "acro method" do
  it "returns acronym of words" do

  end
end
```

Comment: Hint: If you want to *extract* something from an array use `map` not `each`. For example: `sentence.split.map { |w| w[0] }.join` does it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RSpec matchers to check that what your method outputs actually matches what you expect it to do.
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers

```
describe "acro method" do
  it "returns acronym of words" do
    test_sentence = "this is a test acronym"
    expected_acronym = "tiata"

    expect(acronym(test_sentence)).to eq(expected_acronym)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Define Your Input and Expected Output

The point of TDD is to test **expected behavior**. To construct a test, you must define both your *fixture* (a known input value) and your *expectation* (the output you expect your method to produce given a known input value). You then compare the results of your spec with a suitable matcher. For example:

```
def acronym(sentence)
  first_letters = []
  sentence.split.each do |word|
    first_letters << word[0]
  end 
  first_letters.join
end

describe "#acronym" do
  let(:sentence) { 'A very short sentence.' }

  it "returns initial letter of each word" do
    expect(acronym sentence).to eq('Avss')
  end 
end
```

When you run the spec in document format, it should read fairly naturally.

> ```
> $ rspec --format doc foo_spec.rb 
>
> #acronym
>   returns initial letter of each word
>
> Finished in 0.0017 seconds (files took 0.12358 seconds to load)
> 1 example, 0 failures
> ```

If you change your test's expected output from `Avss` to `avss`, then your expectation will fail. A well-written test will give you a useful error like:

> ```
> Failures:
>
>   1) #acronym returns initial letter of each word
>      Failure/Error: expect(acronym sentence).to eq('avss')
>
>        expected: "avss"
>             got: "Avss"
>
>        (compared using ==)
> ```

You can then fix your class or method until the desired behavior is achieved.